# How do I populate two auto-incrementing fields in same Object

Tags: apex, trigger, auto-number

I've a trigger on a custom object `Object_A__c`. Now, I need to populate a receipt number id in a field `receipt_id__c`.

There are two types of receipts X and Y namely. I need to populate the `receipt_id__c` with X-001, X-002,etc., and similarly Y-001, Y-002, etc.,. i thought of using `AutoNumber` field but got stuck since its the same object I'm working on and the auto number field increments for each record irrespective of the type of receipts. I need to handle bulk insert as well.

How should I proceed now?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the receipt number ids need to be consecutive, or just unique?

Comment: @Jeremy : It should be consecutive.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to populate receipt_id__c with {X-0000} or {Y-0000} depending on receipt type. You can create two separate custom objects, let's say: seqX and seqY, add two lookup relations to the Object_A__c then create a formula field (this is your receipt_id__c) as follows:

```
 CASE(TEXT(DocumentType__c), 
   'TypeX', seqX_ref__r.DocX_num__c, 
   'TypeY', seqY_ref__r.DocY_num__c, 
    '')
```

You'll also need to write a trigger that creates new seqX or seqY and assign it to the Object_A__c accordingly (to seqX_ref__c or to seqY_ref__c).

But there is one serious issue - autonumber does not guarantee that will be consecutive i.e. when you insert an object and an exception or validation error occurs you'll see gaps in the sequence.

You can find trigger implementation  here: [CreateSequence.apex](https://gist.github.com/msztandarski/5846664)