# Auto Number Name field dependent on picklist value

Tags: trigger, auto-number

I have a Auto Number standard field (`Name`) of custom object (`Term__c`) which is to be dependent on custom field `Color__c` (picklist) of same custom object.

For each picklist value, such as "red", "blue", "green", `Name` should start from 0, and for each picklist value it should be incremented on creating more records. We have to use trigger.

Can any one let me know how should I proceed?

Comment: Have you had a chance to review the existing questions on Salesforce Stack Exchange about trigger-populated Auto Numbers? Here's [one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13016/how-do-i-populate-two-auto-incrementing-fields-in-same-object) approach from some years back, and [another](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100097/how-to-generate-auto-number-using-triggers) that could be modified for your use case. It's always going to be more efficient to simply use native Auto Number fields, though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the behavior of an auto-number field other than to set a display format, which can use the merge fields Y, M, D, and 0, for year, month, day, and the auto-number counter, respectively. You would need to start with a normal text field then update the value in your trigger/process builder/flow.